# Using multiple arrays in foreach in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, preg-match-all

I've been trying to use foreach with 2 arrays for hours.
Here's my code:

```
function displayTXTList($fileName) {

    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        $contents = file($fileName);
        $string   = implode($contents);
        preg_match_all('#\[\[(\w+)\]\]#u', $string, $name);
        preg_match_all('/style=(\'|\")([ -0-9a-zA-Z:]*[ 0-9a-zA-Z;]*)*(\'|\")/', $string, $name2);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($name[1] as $index => $value) {
            echo '<br/>' . $value, $name2[$index];
        }
    }
}

displayTXTList('smiley2.txt');
```

Here's what I got:

```
sadArray
cryingArray
sunArray
cloudArray
raining
coffee
cute_happy
snowman
sparkle
heart
lightning
sorry
so_sorry
etc...
```

But I want this:

```
sadstyle='background-position: -0px -0px;'
cryingstyle='background-position: -16px -0px;'
sunstyle='background-position: -32px -0px;'
etc...
```

The actual txt file is this:

```
[[sad]]<span class='smiley' style='background-position: -0px -0px;'></span>
[[crying]]<span class='smiley' style='background-position: -16px -0px;'></span>
[[sun]]<span class='smiley' style='background-position: -32px -0px;'></span>
[[cloud]]<span class='smiley' style='background-position: -48px -0px;'></span>
[[raining]]<span class='smiley' style='background-position: -64px -0px;'></span>
etc...
```

How I can do this? I'm new here, so do not down note please :/

Comment: please indent your PHP code well

Comment: What do you mean by "indent"?

Comment: use 'print_r( $name2, true )' to find the array nesting. You just have another level to abstract to get to your values.

Comment: @MarioErmando: I edited your question, this (or similar) is what was meant by Mahan about indenting the code. It makes it more readable.

Comment: @ethrbunny It doesn't show anything, but it does when I set it to 'false'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting an array as string (Hence the `Array` in the output, if you convert an array into string (e.g. by using `echo`), PHP will convert it to `"Array"`). Instead access the match inside the array (I assume group 0 for `$name2`, please check):

```
echo '<br/>' .$value , $name2[0][$index];
                             ^^^--- was missing
```

---

```
function displayTXTList($fileName) {

    if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
        return;
    }

    $string = file_get_contents($fileName);

    $names  = preg_match_all('#\[\[(\w+)\]\]#u', $string, $matches) ? $matches[1] : array();
    $styles = preg_match_all(
        '/style=(\'|\")([ -0-9a-zA-Z:]*[ 0-9a-zA-Z;]*)*(\'|\")/', $string, $matches
    ) ? $matches[0] : array();

    foreach ($names as $index => $name) {
        $style = $styles[$index];
        echo '<br/>', $name, $style;
    }
}

displayTXTList('smiley2.txt');
```

Comment: @MarioErmando: You're welcome. I updated the answer, it shows how the function *could* be written as well, you can improve by using some different functions, change the wording of the variables, exit early etc. - Just read it slowly and think about it a little, not saying it should be written like that, just to give some pointers.